# Use attribute of object as a source of TextInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-admin

I have my object, that is stored in a variable `entityData`. I want to print the currrent values of attributes from my object to `<SimpleForm>`. I assumed it would be simple, but for some reason the values wont print.
My object looks like this:

[image]

And I have tried this code:

```
const entityData = this.state.entityData;
return (
<SimpleForm
    form="post-quick-create"
    resource={this.props.resource}
    toolbar={null}
 >
    <TextInput source={entityData.bgColor} label="Background Color" />
    <TextInput source={entityData.caption} label="Caption" />
    <BooleanInput source={entityData.enabled} label="Enabled" />
    <TextInput source={entityData.image} label="Image" />
    <TextInput source={entityData.name} label="Image" />
    <TextInput source={entityData.textColor} label="Text Color" />
    <TextInput source={entityData.type} label="Type" />
    <SaveButton saving={isSubmitting} onClick={this.handleSaveClick}/>
</SimpleForm>

);
```

I tried to `console.log` the `entityData` variable in the form and it is present as well as all of its attributes. So I am really confused, why I cant print these values to form.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is the code of your **TextInput**?  or is a readymade component from alibrary?

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez Its an already build in component, more here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#textinput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the original `record` that you are setting by `{...this.props}` for your state. Although I do not recommend this, since it can cause some sketchy behaviour later. Also the `source` needs to be a string, not a value like in your example.

```
<SimpleForm {...this.props} record={this.state}>
   <TextInput source='entityData.bgColor' label="Background Color" />
   <TextInput source='entityData.caption' label="Caption" />
   <BooleanInput source='entityData.enabled' label="Enabled" />
   <TextInput source='entityData.image' label="Image" />
   <TextInput source='entityData.name' label="Name" />
   <TextInput source='entityData.textColor' label="Text Color" />
   <TextInput source='entityData.type' label="Type" />
</SimpleForm>
```

Note how I set `record` to `this.state`. This way you should get the values to inputs.